# By design why is it mandatory to specify parameter names when declaring delegate type?

Tags: c#

Why must we specify the parameter name `x` as follows

```
public delegate void XXX(int x);
```

when declaring a delegate type?

For me, the parameter name `x` is unused so it will be simpler if we can rewrite as follows:

```
public delegate void XXX(int);
```

Please let me know why the C# designer "forced" us to specify the parameter names.

### Edit1:

Is `public delegate TResult Func<T1,TResult>(T1 arg1)` more readable than `public delegate TResult Func<T1,TResult>(T1)` ?

Comment: Certainly, as Marc says, it's to document the intention.  What bugs me about this, though, is that there's nothing at all saying the implementing method will use those parameter names.

Comment: Re the Edit1: that is a skewed case; `Func<T,TResult>` is a general purpose delegate, that is intended to fit any use the caller wants - i.e. in that case the `arg1` has no pre-determined intent. But replace that question with `EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs args)` and the meaning of the first parameter in particular is suddenly a lot clearer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It *is* used:

- when coding an invoke, to provide sensible intellisense and to help the developer know which of 4 strings to pass in which position to a method(string,string,string,string) (for example)
- in other tooling - for example implementing an event (or other delegate) and pressing <kbd>tab</kbd> to have the tooling generate a method stub (the parameter names from the delegate become the parameter names of the method-stub)

In both cases this name adds meaning that aids the developer. For example, I have **no idea** what your `x` represents - but name it something better and I'll have a clue.

As an alternative, use `Action<int>` and forget about it.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. It makes sense but it should not be a mandatory. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Probably the same reason as you are forced to specify the name of a method parameter.  For one thing it helps to document the purpose of the parameter.

Which is more readable?

```
public delegate void EventHandler(object source, EventArgs e);

public delegate void EventHandler(object, EventArgs);
```

Comment: Is `public delegate TResult Func<T1,TResult>(T1 arg1)` more readable than `public delegate TResult Func<T1,TResult>(T1)` ?

Comment: @Recycle - that is a skewed case; `Func<T,TResult>` is a *general purpose* delegate, that is intended to fit any use the caller wants - i.e. **in that case** the `arg1` has no pre-determined intent. But replace that question with `EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs args)` and the meaning of the first parameter *in particular* is suddenly a lot clearer